# Android - Make a contact not editable on the phone

Tags: java, android, facebook, contacts

Can someone tell me how to make a contact on a android phone 'non editable', I've seen it done with Facebook contacts but i dont know how to do it my self. Is there a value i have to put with a contact when inserting it into the contacts database? Or a option within the AccountManager?

Thanks in advance... :)

[Edit]
I've found out that the SYnc Provider has to be 'read-only'. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your sync adapter's xml file (e.g. `syncadapter.xml`), define `android:supportsUploading="false"`. This will make the sync adapter "read-only" (i.e. the phone won't be able to upload changes), which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Aha.. Works perfectly, thankyou.. Do you know how to set the display option for a new account when its created?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. Consider creating a separate question for that, I'm not sure if I'll be able to answer it anyway :)

Comment: Setting android:supportsUploading="false" is not working for me for some reason. Other settings in syncadapter.xml are working though, such as android:userVisible="false" which does correctly remove the sync toggle from the account settings UI. Is there some other setting that I am missing?